# proving that $Bx=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, and Let $B$ be an $n\times m$ matrix such that $AB=I_m$.

How can i prove that $Bx=0$ has a single unique solution?

**My proccess so far**:   i think $Bx=0$ has a trivial solution  $x = 0$, and it has independent variables because the number of dependent variables cannot exceed the number of rows, $n$, so the number of independent variables is at least $m−n < 0$.

But that's not a proof and i cant see how to write it down and how to continue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is a solution to $Bx=0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, 
$$
0_m=A\cdot 0_n = A(Bx)=(AB)x = I_m x = x
$$
and so $x=0_m$. So the only possible solution is $0_m$.

Comment: what is $0_m$? i dont know that symbol

Comment: @mila I am using it to denote the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (to differentiate between the scalar 0, and the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: got it thank you,btw can i say that $AB$ is not invertible?

Comment: Since $AB$ is the identity matrix, it *is* invertible: $(AB)^{-1}=AB=I_m$.

Comment: yes sorry i meant invertible, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! (Note that you cannot say that $B$ is invertible, unless $m=n$ -- it is not even a square matrix.)

Comment: but i can say that $n \ge m$ and if $BX=I_n$ so $X=A$ and $m=n$ no? i wonder how to prove that one..

Comment: Not necessarily either. Take $m=1$, $n=2$, for instance, and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $Bx=0$, then we have that

$x=I_mx=A(Bx)=A0=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be a vector such that $Bx = 0$. Premultiply with $A$ gives $$ABx = (AB)x = I_mx = x = 0.$$ We conclude that only the zero vector satisfies this equation and therefor the system has an unique solution.