# proving that $n \ge m$ , $m=n$ and $X=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a follow up question of [proving that Bx=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050922/proving-that-bx-0).

Given  $A$  an $m×n$ matrix, and $B$  an $n×m$ matrix such that $AB=I_m$.

How can i prove that:

1)  $n \ge m$

2) If there is a matrix $X$ such that $BX=I_n$ so $X=A$ and $m=n$

About (1) i tried to look at the rows of matrix $B$ but i cant show it mathematically.

about (2) im not sure that its even true..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns of matrix $B$ are vectors from $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^n$. There are $m$ of them, and when $n \lt m$ they can't form a linearly independent set of vectors; in other words, there is some $x \in \mathbb R^m$ such that $$Bx=0_n$$ and $x \neq 0_m$. But then, $$(AB)x=A(Bx)=A 0_n=0_m$$
which means that $AB \neq I_m$.

Comment: but it said $n>m$ not $n<m$ as you wrote.

Comment: This is a proof by contradiction: you wanted to prove that $n \ge m$, I assumed that $n \lt m$ and this led to a contradiction; therefore,  $n \ge m$.

Comment: got it! can you give me an hint for (2)?

Comment: By what we just proved above, if $AB=I_m$ then $n \ge m$, and if $BX=I_n$ then $m \ge n$. Therefore...

Answer (score 0):

$1$. $I_m=AB\implies Rank(AB)=m$

$m\le Rank(A)$ and $m\le Rank(B)$

$\implies m\le n$.

$2$. Clearly $X$ is of order $m×n$ then $BX=I_n\implies ABX=AI_n\implies I_mX=AI_n\implies X=A$.

Then $AB=I_m$ and $BA=I_n$ implies $m\le n$ and $n\le m\implies m=n$.